# Python 2: How do I condense like terms in a tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I am using a tuple to store the output of a `find -exec stat` command and need to condense it in order to run du on it. The output is a tuple with each item being `(username,/path/to/file)`

I want to condense it to combine like usernames so the end result is `(username,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,etc)`

Is there any way to do this?

Here is the current code that returns my tuple

```
cmd = ['find',dir_loc,'-type','f','-exec','stat','-c','%U %n','{}','+']
process = Popen(cmd,stdout=PIPE)
find_out = process.communicate()
exit_code = process.wait()  

find_out = find_out[0].split('\n')

out_tuple = []
for item in find_out:
    out_tuple.append(item.split(' '))
```

Comment: Fyi, out_tuple is actually a list.

Comment: Have you considered making use of a dictionary of lists, indexed on the username? Seems to be the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `list` of `tuples` or a `list` of `lists` of the form:

```
out_tuple = [('user_one', 'path_one'),
             ('user_three', 'path_seven'),
             ('user_two', 'path_five'),
             ('user_one', 'path_two'),
             ('user_one', 'path_three'),
             ('user_two', 'path_four')]
```

You can do:

```
from itertools import groupby

out_tuple.sort()
total_grouped = []
for key, group in groupby(out_tuple, lambda x: x[0]):
    grouped_list = [key] + [x[1] for x in group]
    total_grouped.append(tuple(grouped_list))
```

This will give you the `list` of `tuples`:

```
print total_grouped
# Prints: 
# [('user_one', 'path_one', 'path_two', 'path_three'),
#  ('user_three', 'path_seven'),
#  ('user_two', 'path_five', 'path_four')]
```

If you started with a `list` of `lists`, then instead of:

```
    total_grouped.append(tuple(grouped_list))
```

You can get rid of the `tuple` construction:

```
    total_grouped.append(grouped_list)
```

I'll say one thing though, you might be better off using something like a `dict` as @BradBeattie suggests. If you're going to perform some operation later on that treats the first item in your `tuple` (or `list`) in a special way, then a `dict` is better.

It not only has a notion of uniqueness in the keys, it's also less cumbersome because the nesting has two distinct levels. First you have the `dict`, then you have the inner item which is a `tuple` (or a `list`). This is much clearer than having two similar collections nested one inside the other.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a dict of lists:

```
out_tuple = [('user1', 'path1'),
             ('user1', 'path2'),
             ('user2', 'path3'),
             ('user1', 'path4'),
             ('user2', 'path5'),
             ('user1', 'path6')]

d={}
for user_name, path in out_tuple:
    d.setdefault(user_name, []).append(path)

print d
```

Prints:

```
{'user2': ['path3', 'path5'], 'user1': ['path1', 'path2', 'path4', 'path6']}
```

Then if you want the output for each user name as a tuple:

```
for user_name in d:
    print tuple([user_name]+d[user_name])
```

Prints:

```
('user2', 'path3', 'path5')
('user1', 'path1', 'path2', 'path4', 'path6')
```

Comment: This was it, looked more in the dict data structure and that's exactly what I needed. Thanks.